# How to solve: Convector Hurley install error Error writing Chaincode package contents: no source files found in

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, convector, hurley

When installing a chaincode with Hurley in a Convector project this error is launched:

```
2019-03-08 08:19:56.808 CST [node-platform] GetDeploymentPayload -> ERRO 003 Error writing folder to tar package no source files found in '/<home-path>/<project-folder>/chaincode'
Error: error getting chaincode code <chaincode>: error getting chaincode package bytes: Error writing Chaincode package contents: no source files found in '<path>'
```

Answer (score 1):

It may happen due to the paths not being readable by the Fabric binaries to install a chaincode.

Check the name of your folder or its path. It may contain some characters that are breaking the path like a `.` (dot) somewhere.